# Why can Relu solve vanishing gradient?

Tags: sigmoid, relu

When it comes to sigmoid, the very first of edges get rarely updated since a lot of multiplication of 0~1. I've learned it's called vanishing gradient.

But why isn't it a problem for Relu? I think the very first of the edges of `relu` also get rarely updated.

Since the `derivative` of `relu` is either 0 or 1, isn't a lot of multiplication of it converge to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting discussion of this issue in this paper here: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v15/glorot11a/glorot11a.pdf

In particular, have a look at the section "Potential Problems" on page 318. It seems like exactly because the derivative is either 0 or 1, but never just "approaching" zero (as in the sigmoid case) that leads to a sparse representation which turns out to help training.